# How to show default payment method as checked at checkout page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, default

When customer go to checkout page default payment method should be shown checked which is Paypal. 
[image]

What is the possible way to do this. Please help guys

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Magento built-in payment methods don't support this ability.

But, if you have custom payment method and your custom js component extends `Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\default.js`, you can use `selectPaymentMethod` method. 
In most cases, it will be enough to call it in the `initObservable` method:

```
define(['Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'], function(Component) {
    initObservable: function () {
        this._super();
        this.selectPaymentMethod();
        ...
    }
});
```

If your payment js component has lazy initialization, you should call `selectPaymentMethod` on some `onReady` event.

Comment: please add more details. this is not understanding

Comment: This solution will rewrite the selected payment method. End-users can't change the payment method anymore.

Answer (score 20):

**One more example with preset default payment method as Credit Card (braintree)**:

`app/code/Company/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': {
                'BalanceInternet_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`app/code/Company/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js`

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method'
], function(
    paymentService,
    checkoutData,
    selectPaymentMethodAction
) {
    'use strict';

    return function(checkoutDataResolver) {
        checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod = function() {
            var availablePaymentMethods = paymentService.getAvailablePaymentMethods(),
                selectedPaymentMethod = checkoutData.getSelectedPaymentMethod(),
                paymentMethod = selectedPaymentMethod ? selectedPaymentMethod : 'braintree';

            if (availablePaymentMethods.length > 0) {
                availablePaymentMethods.some(function (payment) {
                    if (payment.method == paymentMethod) {
                        selectPaymentMethodAction(payment);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        return checkoutDataResolver;
    };
});
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: how to achieve the same for stored credit card ?

Comment: I think this solution is better than accepted answer.

Comment: I have tried this and also the module https://techflarestudio.com/how-to-preselect-default-payment-method-in-magento-2-checkout/ But when i try to default select payment method, place order button is disabled and not able to order. When we check again the already showing selected payment method again then the place order is active. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: The solution worked for me as well thanks!!