# Show my payment method as checked in checkout page in magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment

I have PayPal express checkout payment, I configured it's working fine. But I want that payment checked as default after choosing the shipping method. Please tell me how can I achieve this...As per Magento default, it's not checked. I tried below link but it's not working for me. Please tell me if anything I missed.

[How to show default payment method as checked at checkout page in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159815/how-to-show-default-payment-method-as-checked-at-checkout-page-in-magento-2)

Comment: Clarify your error. Show your code.

Comment: Do you have multiple payment methods enabled?

Comment: Yes multiple payments.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with set order `PayPal express` on first order. So may be first payment method by default selected.