# How to select a shipping method if the default address is present in checkout page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer, shipping-methods, shipping-address

I need to select the first method rendering in the list as the default selected among the shipping methods in the checkout page for a customer whose default shipping address is pre-populated in the checkout page.

**How can we achieve this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show default payment method as checked at checkout page in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159815/how-to-show-default-payment-method-as-checked-at-checkout-page-in-magento-2)