# Magento2 - How to set stored credit card as default payment method?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, credit-card

How to set stored Credit Card as selected by default in Magento2?

If multiple cards are listed in the checkout page.

Comment: have you checked this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/247467/59677

Comment: yes. that is working only for credit card payment method. not for stored credit cards