# Need some advice on Set stored credit card as default payment method magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment

Need to add functionality to **Set Stored credit card as default payment method in payment options** checkout page magento 2 https://prnt.sc/rvdou9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved this functionality using cookie.
Set cookie and get its value and set it on payment method option.

Answer (score 0):

The Magento built-in payment methods don't support this ability.

But, if you have custom payment method and your custom js component extends `Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\default.js`, you can use `selectPaymentMethod` method. 
In most cases, it will be enough to call it in the `initObservable` method:

```
define(['Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'], function(Component) {
    initObservable: function () {
        this._super();
        this.selectPaymentMethod();
        ...
    }
});
```

If your payment js component has lazy initialization, you should call `selectPaymentMethod` on some `onReady` event.

Comment: Could you please provide  a bit more detail ? i want to set store credit card as selected payment option https://prnt.sc/rve6lh

Comment: you want the card to be as a selected which payment method are you using

Comment: Stripe stored card credit card , payment method "stripe"

Comment: there will be one js which will be rendering the payment method there you can use some trick but before you need to debug that from where it's showing

Comment: I've set the store card payment method code and also set the credit card on the frontend using jquery onchange but then place order button does't work , nothing happens after clicking place order button , but once i toggle the payment option ans select the same card then it works.

Answer (score 0):

**One more example with preset default payment method as Credit Card (braintree)**:

`app/code/Company/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': {
                'BalanceInternet_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`app/code/Company/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js`

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method'
], function(
    paymentService,
    checkoutData,
    selectPaymentMethodAction
) {
    'use strict';

    return function(checkoutDataResolver) {
        checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod = function() {
            var availablePaymentMethods = paymentService.getAvailablePaymentMethods(),
                selectedPaymentMethod = checkoutData.getSelectedPaymentMethod(),
                paymentMethod = selectedPaymentMethod ? selectedPaymentMethod : 'braintree';

            if (availablePaymentMethods.length > 0) {
                availablePaymentMethods.some(function (payment) {
                    if (payment.method == paymentMethod) {
                        selectPaymentMethodAction(payment);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        return checkoutDataResolver;
    };
});
```

Comment: I've checked this link -https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159815/how-to-show-default-payment-method-as-checked-at-checkout-page-in-magento-2/247467#247467 but it does'nt shows how to set stored credit card as selected payment method .